# create image flow for images come dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make image flow as shown in this example [image flow](http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/) but the images will come from database at run time, the problem I face is that I need to include the js file that make the flow of the images after AJAX call of loading images is excuted .

I make like this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: uri+"/getAds",

    type: "POST",
    success: function(result){
        adsData = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        var items="" ;
        $.each(adsData,function(index){
            items+="<img src='"+adsData[index].img+"' id="+adsData[index].id+"/>";

        });

        $("#myImageFlow").html(items);
     //   alert("done");
         addScript("scripts/imageflow.js");
    }
```

and here is the function that add the script

```
function addScript(url) {
 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src=url;
 script.type = 'text/javascript';
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

But the script is not executed, I think it need to wait until all images are loaded or some thing like that, what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `getScript` method instead.

```
$.getScript("scripts/imageflow.js");
```

Optionally you can provide a callback handler which will be executed once the script gets loaded.

```
$.getScript("scripts/imageflow.js", function(){
    //You can use any method or properties defined in imageflow.js here
});
```

If there a more images then you might want to wait untill all the images are loaded on the page before executing the imageflow script. You can use img elements `load` method to determine if the image is loaded or not. Try this.

```
success: function(result){
        adsData = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        var items="", imageCount = 0, totalImages = adsData.length ;
        $.each(adsData,function(index, data){
            $("<img id=" + data.id + " />")
            .load(function(){
               imageCount++;//Increment the imageCount 
               if(imageCount == totalImages){
                   //All the images are loaded now load the script
                   $.getScript("scripts/imageflow.js");
               }
            })
            .error(function(){
               imageCount++;//In case of error just increment imageCount
            })
            .attr("src", data.img)
            .appendTo("#myImageFlow");

        });
}
```

Note, in the above script I am attaching a load event handler for each image before setting the `src` attribute and maintaining the count of images loaded. Once the image is loaded the `imageCount` increases and then if the `imageCount` is equal to `totalImages` then load the script which will make sure that all the images are loaded. Also instead of string concatenation to create html I am using `appendTo` method which inserts every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target

References:

- `getScript()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/
- `appendTo()`: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: same problem, script is not executing!!

Comment: I make an alert at the top of imageflow.js and it works, but the alert in the function that create the flow of the images does not, it depend on dom ready!!

Comment: Dom is ready so it should execute the Dom ready code. Did u used my edited code?

Comment: ,Yes I did, and it doesn't make any change !!
I tried to put the including to the script file at the end of HTML page, and make alert in the script file, when I click enter it executes the flow of the image, but without making the alert it doesn't executes !!

Comment: @ShankarSangoli -Oh yeah. I like this. I think I'm going to use it. How would you add a spinner to this so that it stopped when the images loaded?